# Is it possible to set storage limits for different users in my Dropbox business account?

Tags: dropbox

I want to set storage limit for different user in my Dropbox business account. Means I have a business account with storage limit of 2TB and want to create sub user(sub account) in my main business account with different storage limit i.e. sub user 1 having storage limit of 50 GB, sub user 2 having storage limit of 100 GB and sub user 3 having storage limit of 80 GB and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker this is not off-topic. i am not looking for any setting thing from dropbox, i am looking for API options to do this, if anyone has used.

Answer (score 0):

No, Dropbox Business accounts do not offer the ability to set individual member quotas, either via the Dropbox product or Dropbox API.